# `yum install` on CentOS 7 states installed size of 578mb, then fails requiring 75+GB more space on /

Tags: centos, yum, openvz, proxmox

I have ~10Gb available on `/`.After running `yum install kolab` on a new CentOS container yum states the following:

```
Total size: 234 M
Installed size: 578 M
```

However, the install then fails with the error:

```
Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
  At least 77224MB more space needed on the / filesystem
```

I am completely new to CentOS, coming from the Debian world, so maybe there is something simple I am missing, but it seems to be pretty odd to me that a ~500MB package would take more than 100x the space required to install. I have destroyed the container and created a new one, but I still keep getting the same error. This is an OpenVZ container running on Proxmox 3.4 (Debian based).

Is there something I am doing wrong, is something broken in my system, or does it really just require 75+GB to install a ~500MB file on CentOS?

I ran `df` on the host and installed postfix. The *postfix* installation succeeded without any issues. However, running a `df` on the container after installing *postfix* shows the same result as before the install. I then ran `yum install spamassasin` and again got odd results, requiring an additional ~3GB of space on `/` despite an 'installed size' of 24MB (see pastebin link below). Interestingly, on a whim, I ran `yum install glibc-headers, which had a dependency only on`kernel-headers`, which installed successfully. I then tried`yum install spamassassin`and it also succeeded. Trying`yum install kolab` still failed with the odd space requirement.

Considering this is just a test container and have ample space available on the host, I am tempted to increase the containers disk size to ~100GB, trying `yum install kolab` again and seeing what happens... Not sure if trying that could break anything though?

---

[Full output of `yum install kolab` (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/1mbr13yY)

[Full output of `yum install spamassasin` (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/wBL12hZQ)

Original Results of `df` on container:

```
[root@kolab-test ~]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      10485760  4096  10481664   1% /
devtmpfs         2097152     0   2097152   0% /dev
tmpfs            2097152     0   2097152   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2097152    84   2097068   1% /run
tmpfs            2097152     0   2097152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Results of `df` on container after `yum install postfix` succeeded:

```
[root@kolab-test ~]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      10485760  4096  10481664   1% /
devtmpfs         2097152     0   2097152   0% /dev
tmpfs            2097152     0   2097152   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2097152    56   2097096   1% /run
tmpfs            2097152     0   2097152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Results of `df` on host:

```
root@pve0:~# df
Filesystem                   1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev                             10240         0      10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                          4944756       572    4944184   1% /run
/dev/mapper/pve-root          17288012   1699600   14710232  11% /
tmpfs                             5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          9889500     56680    9832820   1% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/pve-data          35221176    180288   35040888   1% /var/lib/vz
/dev/fuse                        30720        52      30668   1% /etc/pve
/dev/sda1                     66410964  25844656   40566308  39% /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-2
/dev/sdc1                    482906752 150778848  332127904  32% /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
/dev/sdb1                     66411008  24674788   41736220  38% /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-0
ceph-fuse                   2468143104 767275008 1700868096  32% /mnt/cephfs
/mnt/cephfs/pve/private/101   10485760      4096   10481664   1% /var/lib/vz/root/101
devtmpfs                       2097152         0    2097152   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/dev
tmpfs                          2097152         0    2097152   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/dev/shm
tmpfs                          2097152        60    2097092   1% /var/lib/vz/root/101/run
tmpfs                          2097152         0    2097152   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/sys/fs/cgroup
/mnt/cephfs/pve/private/300   10485760      4096   10481664   1% /var/lib/vz/root/300
tmpfs                           419432        28     419404   1% /var/lib/vz/root/300/run
tmpfs                             5120         0       5120   0% /var/lib/vz/root/300/run/lock
tmpfs                          1677720         0    1677720   0% /var/lib/vz/root/300/run/shm
```

Comment: What does `df` on the host node look like?

Comment: You are quite right, yum seems to have gone off the deep end. Some of the values look OK, but then it thinks kernel headers would require 2GB. 500MB is very little for 362 packages so I would assume more space used, but not this much. What does it say if you take some of the packages it wants to install, like postfix or spamassassin and install those by themselves? Does it then also say crazy numbers?

Comment: If you try to install kolab on the host, not a container, do you see the same weird space requirements?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick While the host is not in production, it is the test environment for my production gear, so I try not to mess with it. I would try  other alternatives rather than mess with the host... Additionally, the host is Debian based (Proxmox) and therefore I could not try the same installation method